# ROS determines the size of an array itself? Really

Tags: ros, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the ros code in ros msg format:

```
Ephemeris[] eph
```

which is equivalent of this in c:

```
Ephemeris *eph;
```

Now I have heard that ros determines itself the size of an array. One does not have to give it size.

Now for the C code inorder for me to iterate in the array I need to know the size of the array but I believe in ros, I dont.

So if I am writing a C code and I want to access the msg format and I want to iterate through the array eph, how can I do it without knowing the size of eph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75184/ros-determines-the-size-of-an-array-itself?-really/) by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-08-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a simple answer: ROS doesn't support C (in this way).

ROS messages are C++ and in that case the [] is translated to an std::vector, which has a size.

C-ports like for rosserial usually do have an additional size value.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on 2013-08-28**:
oh cool, so I can use vector::begin() and vector::end() to navigate in the array. I will incorportate my C code into C++ then. Just one question. I know that in ROS one does not need to declare size of an array so according to your analogy, I can infer that a dynamic vector is created everytime. If this is true than it means that ROS is powerful enough to know the size of any array itself.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-28**:
Yes, in C++ any [] in a message is a vector. This might be different for fixed size arrays.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-28**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg?action=show&redirect=ROS%2FMessage_Description_Language#Fields gives a description of how messages are translated into python and C++.